# Phpmyadmin error Notice in ./index.php#305 Undefined index: utf8

Tags: mariadb, phpmyadmin

I installed PHPMyAdmin and work with MariaDB 10.6. When accessing the main page I receive an alert with the message:
Notice in ./index.php#305 Undefined index: utf8

[image]

Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: The "main page" of your app?  Or of PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: on PHPMyAdmin @RickJames